# How to declare multiple similar variables in python?

Tags: python, loops, variables

How can I declare multiple (about 50) variables that count from slider1 to slider50 ? Is there an efficient way, like looping with for?

```
slider1 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
slider2 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
slider3 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
slider4 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
slider5 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
slider6 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
slider7 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
slider8 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
slider9 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
slider10 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
```

Comment: The short answer is: Don't declare individual variables dynamically, create an object like a dictionary with key-value pairs instead

Comment: `sliders = [models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="") for _ in range(50)]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using a Dictionary for this task:

```
d = {}

for x in range(1,10):
        d["slider{0}".format(x)]= models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.Slider, default=50, label="")
```

Comment: If the names have no meaning and are just the same name with a number at the end, a `list` would be much more appropriate.

Comment: If the names have no meaning, yes.
If they have meaning... No :) It is a specific requirement so I'd assume that they do have a meaning.