# How can I declare multiple similar variables in Python?

Tags: python

I have several variables, each having a different use, which are declared in the following way:

```
a= defaultdict(list)
b= defaultdict(list)
c= defaultdict(list)
d= defaultdict(list)
e= defaultdict(list)
f= defaultdict(list)
#and several more such variables
```

With regard to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185246/how-to-declare-multiple-similar-variables-in-python), a list will not reduce the effort, as I need to use all these variables in different tasks (If I create a list, I will again have to declare each one of these variables by list indices, which is a similar effort)

Is there a way I can reduce the number of lines in declaring all these variables?

Comment: If you're not able to use a list then it sounds more like a much bigger problem, you should ask about the problem you're trying to solve by doing this

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I stated my problem: I just want to optimise that block of code (my code has 15 such variables, all declared the same way; I want to know if instead of 15, I can do it in fewer lines of code). To be clear, I am not running into any issues because of the above declaration. I just want optimisation

Comment: You say that you are not satisfied with putting it all in a list, but what about using a dict or a namedtuple instead, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)?

Comment: @Alex, it is an in-built module, in collections. so, by saying defaultdict(list), I declare a dictionary where the values are lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign each with this format:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f = [defaultdict(list) for i in range(6)]
```

In this way you are creating a list of `defaultdict(list)` which will assign each of them to a variable. So each variable will be initiated to `defaultdict(list)` independent to the other variables.

`6` would be number of your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand the problem... but maybe you are looking to `eval`.
You can declare dynamically variable from string.

An example:

```
for i in range(50):
    exec('my_var_%s = {"a":%s}'% (i,i))

print(my_var_1)
# {'a': 1}
```

I also advice you to have a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). (even if it's for `eval` function).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The shortest is probably:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f = [defaultdict(list)]*6
```

which is a shorthand way of saying:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f = defaultdict(list), defaultdict(list), defaultdict(list), ...
```